# Traversing HTML tags Tree with CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <div id="navbar" >
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="trigger"><span><p></p></span></a></li>
        <li><a id="target"><span><p></p></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

hey guys, I've got a question, if it wouldn't causing any inconvenience to you guys, in relation with traversing in HTML tree.

I already know how to choose the `<a id="trigger"></a>` with this syntax:

`div>div.header>div#navbar>ul#nav>li>a#trigger:hover {CSS}` will trigger changes.

But here's the problem, I wanted to target the `<a id="target""></a>` tag underneath it but I haven't found the right syntax for accessing the `<a id="affected"></a>` there.

I want when I hover the id="trigger", the id="target" will be affected.

I've already tried using + selectors to target that id, alas, the trials ended in vain.

Is it possible to affect that id?

Comment: The given structure won't allow you to do what you're trying to do, as you can't *go upwards* using css. So either you'll use something like shown by isherwood (with changing some of your markup) or you'll need to use js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the adjacent sibling selector:

```
#trigger:hover + #target {}
```

Or maybe the sibling combinator, which doesn't require that the second element be directly adjacent:

```
#trigger:hover ~ #target {}
```

http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors

UPDATE: As is stated in the comments below, the selectors must actually be siblings. In the original structure, they're not.

```
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <div id="navbar" >
      <ul id="nav">
        <li class="one"><a id="trigger">Trigger</a></li>
        <li class="two"><a id="target">Target</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.one:hover + .two {color: red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Gmz9/1/

Here's another approach which doesn't require classes or IDs on the li elements:

```
#nav li:first-child:hover + li {color: red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Gmz9/2/

Each approach has its pitfalls.

---

By the way,

```
div>div.header>div#navbar>ul#nav>li>a#trigger:hover {}
```

could probably be as well written as

```
#navbar #trigger:hover {}
```

saving you and the browser both some work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @isherwood.

I've already tried `div>div.header>div#navbar>ul#nav>li>a#trigger:hover+a#affected` here and `a#trigger:hover+a#affected` yet none has shown me the result that I want.

Comment: For this to work, the ids would need to be placed on the li-elements. +1 anyways, as I don't think there is any other way without using js.

Comment: Obviously I didn't read the OP very carefully. I stand corrected. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Gmz9

Comment: I've tried:

`#navbar #trigger:hover~#target`
`#navbar>#trigger:hover~#target`

and none works.

Comment: I updated my solution. Yoshi is right. The elements would have to actually be siblings, which means you need to select the li elements. There are many ways to do that. Updated fiddle (working): http://jsfiddle.net/5Gmz9/1/

Comment: Try the second one I posted. I still forget that jsfiddle changes the URL when you update a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5Gmz9/1/

Comment: @isherwood so the only one that needed the hover state isn't the `<a></a>` but the `<li></li>`?

Comment: Yes, because the a tags aren't siblings but the li tags are.

Comment: Added another option in my answer. Sorry for the zillion edits. :-)

Comment: Oh, btw, another question.. sorry @isherwood, how about if the id got reversed? Let's say the positions of the ids were exchanged. I've tried using + and ~ and nothing worked.

Comment: Yeah, you can't select a previous sibling. You'd need something like jQuery for that (which makes it very easy).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but I found it trying to traverse up the DOM. I found ":has()" will also work, without a parent item class, and a bit more control than first-child:

```
li:has(> #trigger):hover + li > #target {color:red}
```

Or in my case, with a disabled checkbox (because .Net adds a `<span class="aspNetDisabled">` above the disabled element):

```
.aspNetDisabled:has(> input:disabled:checked) + .slider {...
```